# Relate $ \langle X\,,\mathcal{A}^{*}\mathcal{A}\,X\rangle $ and $\langle X\,,\mathcal{A}\,X\rangle $

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the Frobenius inner products $
\langle X\,,\mathcal{A}^{*}\mathcal{A}\,X\rangle
$ and $\langle X\,,\mathcal{A}\,X\rangle $ where $\mathcal{A}$ is some operator and $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ is the adjoint operator.

I am interested in finding a suitable bound for the first inner product. I understand the
second inner product fairly well and know a suitable lower bound. Is there something I can say about the sizes of the inner products with respect to one another?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious estimate that I can think of is
\begin{align}
\langle X, \mathcal{A}^\ast\mathcal{A} X\rangle =\langle \mathcal{A}X, \mathcal{A} X\rangle = \|\mathcal{A}X\|^2 \leq \|\mathcal{A}\|_{\text{op}}^2\|X\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Dear Jacky, thank you for your answer. I was more looking more for showing $<X\,\mathcal{A}^{*}\mathcal{A}X\rangle \ge \langle X\,,\mathcal{A}X\rangle$. For an operator $\mathcal{A}$ of my interest, not symmetric, this seems "true"(numerically) but I can't show it